# How to share dispatcher servlet in multi-module spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module

I'm trying to write Spring boot multi module application, where I separate modules not by logical layer (like a web/services/dao), but by it domain area.

As result I want to have application with separated contexts with structure like

```
root-context
|- UsersModule
|- CompaniesModule
|- InvoicesModule
|- etc...
```

Each module should provide it's own controller(s), service(s) and so on. But I want to start only 1 embeded servlet container (tomcat) and 'share' it to all modules.

Here is my Application class (Root context)

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProcampConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.yvasylchuk.procamp.config")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ProcampApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .parent(ProcampApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .child(UserModuleConfiguration.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
                .sibling(CompanyModuleConfiguration.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
                .run(args);
    }


}
```

And here is Configuration class for User module (Company module configured in same way)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.yvasylchuk.procamp.user")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "org.yvasylchuk.procamp.user.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
public class UserModuleConfiguration {
}
```

In this case User module starts successfully, but Company module fails to start with errors like:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-08 15:58:29.685 ERROR 15324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
```

So it seems that both CompanyModule and UserModule trying to start its own servlet container. Can someone help me with configuration please?

Comment: Have you considered a microservice architecture instead? See Spring Microservices in Action, [page 4](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/0/121cbdc-f909-43f5-8dc0-165be989a3a3/SCh-01.pdf) for reasoning.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply, but microservices is not what I want to do on first stages of development.